# My Sites Showing 404 Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, mysites

I created My Sites site collection on the root of the application. But when I click 'About Me', I get the 404 error.

[image]

I followed the standard procedure to create the site collection in this URL https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000286168-how-to-configure-my-site-host-in-sharepoint-2019. I created the sites in the root of the application path.

I added the 'personal' path in the Managed Paths. I am able to access the One Drive using the URL https:///personal/<user_name> but I get the following error when  I click the 'About Me' button. Kindy help.

Answer (score 0):

Then is means that the Home Page has been deleted. To get it back, go to any other site collection, then Site Contents.

Copy all the text in yellow below once in Site Contents :
[image]

Go to the site collection where you get the 404 error and paste it to the end of the link after the site name :
[image]

The page will display in the Site Contents screen. Go to the Recycle Bin :
[image]

Tick the box next to Home and then Restore :
[image]

The site is restored :
[image]

Be careful when deleting pages from the Site Pages library – don’t delete the Home page or it causes the above issue.
[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "**√**" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Hi Jinwei, this is for My Site Host, site collection, you can see the URL is https://<URL>/personal/person.aspx. I did not delete any page, I just created the My Sites Host Site Collection out of the box